# Reassemble mdadm Raid after Reinstall OS

Tags: linux, raid

i created a level 1 Raid with this manual: https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Software-RAID/
Everything worked fine. No i installed a new OS ( from Ubuntu Server to Linux Mint ) and wanted do activate the Raid again.
As described in the manual i should just have to install mdadm and then it should work. So i don't made a backup of the mdadm.conf.

The Problem seems to be that /dev/sda1 and /dev/sdb1 are not automatically startet with the system. The Raid is based on these two partitions.

When i try to reassemble with /dev/sda and /dev/sdb (`mdadm --assemble /dev/md0 /dev/sda /dev/sdb`) it of course says `/dev/sda has no superblock - assembly aborted`.

When i start `partprobe` the devices /dev/sda1 and /dev/sdb1 shows up, but then reassembling with these (`mdadm --assemble /dev/md0 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1`) says `/dev/sda1 is busy - skipping` for both devices.

The Raid partitions on the devices are just fine.

Normally `mdadm --examine --scan --verbose` shows nothing, but after `partprobe` it shows the correct information:

```
ARRAY /dev/md/0  level=raid1 metadata=1.2 num-devices=2 UUID=c5311fcb:ff37d50c:283b8948:bfce180d name=zeus:0
   devices=/dev/sda1,/dev/sdb1
```

`fdisk -l` shows the correct raid paritions for both devices:

```
Festplatte /dev/sda: 1,84 TiB, 2000398934016 Bytes, 3907029168 Sektoren
Festplattenmodell: WDC WD20EFRX-68E
Einheiten: Sektoren von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
Sektorgröße (logisch/physikalisch): 512 Bytes / 4096 Bytes
E/A-Größe (minimal/optimal): 4096 Bytes / 4096 Bytes
Festplattenbezeichnungstyp: gpt
Festplattenbezeichner: 4E14731F-4C78-4E77-A0B7-ADA011526606

Gerät      Anfang       Ende   Sektoren Größe Typ
/dev/sda1    2048 3907020976 3907018929  1,8T Linux RAID
```

`mdadm --examine /dev/sda1` also shows the correct information:

```
/dev/sda1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : c5311fcb:ff37d50c:283b8948:bfce180d
           Name : zeus:0
  Creation Time : Thu Aug 23 19:03:54 2018
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 2

 Avail Dev Size : 3906754737 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
     Array Size : 1953377344 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3906754688 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
    Data Offset : 264192 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=264112 sectors, after=49 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 18689632:e3a07bad:ca72bf0c:5a911399

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Mon Oct 12 13:23:53 2020
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 16 sectors
       Checksum : 5ce5c973 - correct
         Events : 33882


   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

I hope anyone could help me out.
Thanks in advance!
Kind regards.